# Car Stereo Hookup

Tags: power

We are installing a new stereo into our '57 Chevy.  The stereo has a left and right output.  The car has only one front and one rear speaker.  Can you hook both left and right ouputs wires to the individual speakers?

Comment: Typical car amps have four stereo outputs: two front, two back (i.e. 8 speaker wires in 4 pairs). Since they're typically a bridge-output amp, you absolutely do not want to short these outputs to each other (in any configuration). Your question doesn't contain anywhere near enough info for a meaningful answer alas.

Answer (score 2):

You can hook one channel to the front, and the other channel to the rear. It won't give you the conventional stereo image, but it will be stereo, and is the most practical way to solve it without extra stuff.

You cannot simply connect channels together to get mono.

Making some assumptions about how the amplifier is configured, presumably full bridge on both outputs, you could string the back speaker between L+ and R+, and the front one between L+ and R-. That would give you mono in the front, and a Haffler 'rear' channel, which would be different to the front, expansive, but not really stereo, and with a lower power capability. If the amp isn't full bridge, this trick won't work.

If you used L+ R- to the front, and L- R+ to the back, you'd have mono all round. But I don't see any advantage of this over the stereo of the first simplest solution.